# How to show $2-2/x - \log_2(x) \geq 0$ for $x \in [1,2]$?

Tags: inequality

I have [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2760336/91818) to [Binary tree where every internal vertex is of degree 3.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2758370/binary-tree-where-every-internal-vertex-is-of-degree-3), but it requires a proof of the following:

**Question**: How to show $2-2/x - \log_2(x) \geq 0$ for $x \in [1,2]$?

[Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=when%20is%202-2%2Fx%20-%20log_2(x)%3E%3D0) indicates it's true, although you need to click on "approximate form" and "more digits", when it says it's true when `1.000000000000000000<=x<=2.0000000000000000000`.

We have equality when $x=1$ and $x=2$, so the left-hand side is not increasing on the interval $[1,2]$, which makes it hard to prove via derivatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: define $$f(x)=2-\frac{2}{x}-\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)}$$ and calculate $$f(1),f(2)$$ and solve the equation $$f'(x)=0$$ for $x$

Comment: This seems to work:  Setting $f(x) = 2 - 2/x - \ln x / \ln 2$ we compute $f'(x) = 2/x^2 - 1 / (\ln (2) x).$  Solving for $f'(x)=0$ with $x \in [1,2]$, we obtain a unique solution when $x = \ln (4)$, and $f(x) \simeq 0.086 > 0$.  Thus $f(x)$ achieves a unique maximum on $[1,2]$, and increases from $f(1)=0$ to $f(\ln 4)$ then decreases to $f(2)=0$.  Thus $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in [1,2]$.

Comment: A nice solution Rebecca!

Answer (score 2):

The function
$$
f(x) = 2 - \frac 2x - \frac{\ln x}{\ln 2}
$$
 is (strictly) *concave* in the interval $[1, 2]$ since
$$ 
 f''(x) = -\frac{4}{x^3} + \frac{1}{x^2 \ln 2 } 
 = \frac{1}{x^2 \ln 2} \left( 1- \frac {4 \ln 2}x \right)
 \le  \frac{ 1- 2 \ln 2 }{x^2 \ln 2} < 0
$$
for $1 \le x \le 2$, therefore its graph lies *above* the 
line segment from $(1, f(1))$ to $(2, f(2))$.

You already noticed that $f(1) = f(2) = 0$, so the conclusion follows.

(More generally, any concave function on a closed interval attains
it minimum at one of the interval end points.)

Answer (score 0):

Let $$f(x)=2-\frac2x-\frac{\log x}{\log2}$$ Then $$\int_1^2 f(x)\,dx=\left[2x-2\log x-\frac{x(\log x-1)}{\log 2}\right]_1^2=2-2\log2-\frac{2(\log2-1)}{\log2}-\frac1{\log2}>0$$ Now all you have to do is show that $x=1,2$ are the only points where $f$ crosses the $x$-axis.